# How can I assign "middle click" to a button on my mouse?

Tags: mouse, preferences

How can I assign "middle click" to a button on my mouse?

I am not seeing it in `Preferences > Mouse`, and every google search just returns results about how to set it up with Apple's Magic mouse.

I am *not* using an Apple mouse. Specifically I am using this [logitech](http://www.eteknix.com/logitech-moving-away-mouse-production/) mouse.

Comment: Go here: [Logitech Support](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/downloads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [Logitech Control Centre](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/logitech-control-center-for-macintosh-os-x) System Preference Pane

You het a new Preference Pane "Logitech Control Center"
You will get show attached Logitech Mice etc. Choose the one you want and then you will get a screen to assign buttons to actions